# How small can you make a python install?

Tags: python, installation, storage

I'm trying to run a python script on a machine, that has very limited storage(<3MB) and not yet python installed. Is there a way for me to achieve that? Expanding the storage is in this case not possible.

Comment: https://github.com/micropython/micropython?